# Override accessor or assign the value in constructor

Tags: oop, overriding, accessor

I have a question on object-oriented programming.
If there is a attribute which has different value in sub-classes. It should create a abstract accessor in the super-class, then override it in the sub-classes. Or create a protected instance variable in base-class, and assign the default value in the sub-class constructor?

Let's see the code example code:

Choice 1:

```
class BaseClass {
    public abstract int GetFoo();
}

class SubClass {
    public int GetFoo() {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Choice 2:

```
class BaseClass {
    protected int _foo;

    public int GetFoo() {
        return _foo;
    }
}

class SubClass {
    public SubClass() {
        _foo = -1;
    }
}
```

Or any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the first approach of providing a getter that can be overridden in the derived classes to provide a different value, instead of creating protected members in my class which are also package-private and violate the encapsulation principle.